# how to configure micronaut to use postgtres in place of mysql

Tags: postgresql, micronaut

I'm new to micronaut and I'm following this [official guide](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-hibernate-reactive-gradle-kotlin.html#using-mysql) which works fine: when running `./gradlew run` (or test) a mysql container runs and the framework automatically connects to it.
Starting from the [original basecode](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-hibernate-reactive-gradle-kotlin.zip) I've tried to use postgresql instead.

By changing:

```
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages:
        - 'example.micronaut.domain' 
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show-sql: true
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update 
        connection:
          db-type: postgres # here


...


test-resources:
  containers:
    postgres:
      image-name: postgres:latest
```

but running it raises an error:

```
01:24:04.625 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder]

Message: Could not resolve placeholder ${auto.test.resources.jpa.default.properties.hibernate.connection.url}
```

I guess this does not apply to postgres?

> When the application is started locally — either under test or by
> running the application — resolution of the datasource URL is detected
> and the Test Resources service will start a local MySQL docker
> container, and inject the properties required to use this as the
> datasource.

According to the modules test resources it should be everything fine, but I guess I should put the connection URL myself on the yaml? What else is it missing or wrong? Will the container raise up with the one I've placed?

---

### Update

After trying to see what was needed to be changed on the `build.gradle` the container nows runs when `./gradlew run` is executed. But the following error is thrown:

```
16:06:32.826 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR org.hibernate.reactive.errors - HR000057: Failed to execute statement [select * from information_schema.sequences]: could not execute query 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ongres/scram/common/stringprep/StringPreparation
```

Here is my current build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.6.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.6.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.6.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.6.7"
    id("io.micronaut.test-resources") version "3.6.7"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "example.micronaut"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    kapt("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    kapt("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-reactive")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
//    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-mysql-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-vertx-pg-client")

    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
//    testResourcesService("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    compileOnly("org.graalvm.nativeimage:svm")

    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-vertx-pg-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("example.micronaut.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("example.micronaut.*")
    }
    testResources {
        additionalModules.add("hibernate-reactive-postgresql")
    }
}
```

and my `application.yml`

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-guide
netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3
#tag::jpa[]
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages:
        - 'example.micronaut.domain' # <1>
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show-sql: true
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update # <2>
        connection:
          db-type: postgres # <3>
    reactive: true
#end::jpa[]
```

I've also tried to add what was suggested below:

```yaml
datasources:
  default:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    db-type: postgresql
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: POSTGRES
jpa.default.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

but I got the same error

Comment: can you add your build.gradle file to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `build.gradle` is not part of your question and you initially started with MySQL, I suspect you did not modify the `gradle.build` file.

```
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("example.micronaut.*")
    }
    testResources {
        additionalModules.add("hibernate-reactive-mysql") // <-- this needs to be removed
    }
}
```

Furthermore make sure you use these values in the `application.yml`

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: deleteme
datasources:
  default:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    db-type: postgresql
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: POSTGRES
jpa.default.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3
```

Important is `datasources.default.db-type` and the JDBC driver that indicates test resources what you want to do.

Comment: almost there: there was sure a problem with the build.gradle! I've updated the question with what I've done, and added some further information to better investigate this.